# Why does my TV trip a GFCI outlet on another circuit?

Tags: receptacle, gfci, television

I'm in a 2006 mobile home that has a GFCI outlet behind my microwave it's the only plug I have for it. There are five more regular plugs downstream from it that all say GFCI on them because they're protected by that one GFCI behind the microwave.

The television is the next outlet down from the last plug in the daisy chain.  There are no other items plugged into the daisy chain after the microwave, but when I turn on the tv it pops the GFCI to the microwave and kills those other outlets.  The tv continues to work but all the outlets in the kitchen are dead until I reset the GFCI behind the microwave.

This didn't happen while the old microwave was plugged in and the tv was turned on. Not sure why the new microwave would change anything since it's only showing the time. Can't understand what the tv has to do with anything since it stays on after the GFCI and 5 outlets are dead. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried a different outlet for the TV, and have you tried unplugging the microwave?

Comment: check the wiring.. make sure the neutral from the GFCI  doesn't continue into the tv outlet.

Comment: Multi wire branch circuits do tend to have problems with GFCI’s +

Comment: Can you get us a photo of the inside of the box for the GFCI (with the breaker for the circuit off, of course?)

Comment: I haven't tried unplugging the tv and microwave yet, but I will

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to make every receptacle on the line a GFCI receptacle. That would require you to remove the circuit from the load side of the original GFCI and pigtail it to the circuit and install each receptacle on the line side. That will give you GFCI protection but if there is a trip it will only be for the equipment you have plugged in at that receptacle.

You can also have some receptacles GFCI's and feed the downstream receptacles off of them.

Attached is a drawing that will help you show how to wire this.

[image]

Hope this helps